# Does cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.12.jar and neethi-3.0.3.jar should be present together in webapp folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, cxf

For Soap service implemented using cxf, I am placing cxf related jars under `webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder. The listing of the lib folder is like this:

```
cxf-core-3.1.12.jar              
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.1.12.jar    
neethi-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.12.jar    
cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.12.jar        
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.12.jar  
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.1.12.jar   
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.12.jar    
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.12.jar       
xmlschema-core-2.2.2.jar
```

I am using tomcat and have placed all these jars in `app/lib` folder

```
geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar
geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar
geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
```

under lib folder which is referenced by tomcat common.loader in catalina.properties.

I really wanted to put all cxf jars along with geronimo jars under app/lib so that going forward once we have more soap services, every webapp doesn't  replicate all cxf jars under its webapp folder. I found while testing that if I place all cxf jars under app/lib it doesnt work with different errors.

Some errors are related to neethi older version present in app/lib folder, 
xmlschema older version jars already present under app/lib, similarly older version of wsdl4j jar present. I may not be able to upgrade the versions of neethi 2.x to 3.x as required at the moment.

My question is if I place only cxf related jars under app/lib and keep neethi, xmlschema, wsdl4j jars under webapp folder, I get exception like

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
```

I dont really understand why this doesn't work. I was thinking that webappclass loader will load the neethi and other 2 jars from webapp folder location so it should have worked. Any suggestion why it doesnt work and any alternatives I can try.

I tried various combinations and found placing together all these jars only works:

```
cxf-core-3.1.12.jar              
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.1.12.jar    
neethi-3.0.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.12.jar    
cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.12.jar        
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.12.jar  
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.1.12.jar   
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.12.jar    
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.12.jar  
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.12.jar       
xmlschema-core-2.2.2.jar

org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl
```